# Opening bios update file for p8z77-v deluxe motherboard

Tags: bios

When I download the Bios update file I get this: P8Z77-V-DELUXE-ASUS-1805.zip. When I try to open it I get this: P8Z77-V-DELUXE-ASUS-1805.CAP. But Windows keep asking "the program used to create that file". It is suppose to be easy. What did I do wrong? I downloaded from this address: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=fr-fr&m=P8Z77-V+DELUXE. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ASUS AI Suite installed there should be an option to update your BIOS from Windows. From the update screen you can download from Internet or since you have already downloaded the file choose "Update BIOS from file" and follow the onscreen instructions.

NOTE: Don't have anything else running and be prepared to reboot after doing the update.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open this file in Windows.

To flash the new BIOS update, copy the file to the top level of a USB stick, reboot into the BIOS and use the flash update tool found there.

Comment: ...and if you have no idea what any of this means, you probably shouldn't flash your BIOS.

Comment: @Shinrai This a new (and my first) "build" and I found a lot of contradictory information concerning the necessity of updating the Bios.